# XCTest test C function build Failed

Tags: xcode, xctest

I wrote a C function, when I want test this function using XCTest in Xcode, get a error.

---

`List.h` have a function define.

```
#ifndef List_h
#define List_h

#include <stdio.h>

List initList();

#endif /* List_h */
```

---

`Test.m` code 
    #import 
    #include "List.h"

```
@interface ListTest : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation ListTest

- (void)testExample {
    initList();
}

@end
```

When I press command + U, Build Failed!

Error messages:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_initList", referenced from:
      -[ListTest testExample] in ListTest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find reason.

I need to add the implementation file (*.c file) to the Unit Test target so it gets compiled in. Include the header is not enough.

Comment: If you have to include an implementation file in your test target, you have things set up incorrectly. I just created a brand new project and was able to call my C function from my test, no problem.